# As a Gnome Bard in a Pathfinder Campaign, is there any way to obtain the Fire Music Feat without Multi-Classing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, multi-classing, bard, racial-traits

I am in a campaign where I want to be a Gnome Bard that can use the Fire Descriptor for the Music Damage, but my GM will only allow me to Multi-class into either Druid or Cleric For campaign purposes.  Is there any hope for me?  Maybe with a trait or another Feat?

Ref: [Fire Music Feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fire-music)

Comment: Just a note: from an optimization perspective, that feat is *unbelievably* awful. Harsh requirements, and changing things to fire damage is a **bad** thing since fire is the worst of the energy types. Plus, using bard spells to deal direct damage (or summoning!) is not a good use of bard spellcasting. I get that it's cool and presumably fits the character, but just be aware that you may be badly shooting yourself in the foot by qualifying for, taking, and using that feat. There may be better alternatives for realizing a fire-bard than that.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the [Arcane Talent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/arcane-talent) feat to learn [spark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spark), a 0-level spell with the [fire] descriptor.  The wording of the feat should satisfy the necessary requirements:

> Choose a 0-level spell from the sorcerer/wizard spell list. You can cast this spell three times per day as a spell-like ability.

The [Paizo FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qow) clarifies that spell-like abilities count as being able to cast that specific spell for prerequisites, and (right underneath the previous question) by default will count as arcane spells from the sorc/wizard list.

You should probably also consider the [Pyromaniac](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/gnome) alternate racial trait, since it augments fire spells, but sadly it doesn't grant any arcane casting that would qualify you for the Fire Music feat.

That said, I'm not really sure *why* the feat requires the spell be arcane, so it might be worth discussing options with your DM.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Magician archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo---bard-archetypes/magician).
It allows to expand your spells known at levels 2, 6, 10, 14 and 18 from another arcane caster list.
The archetype changes a number of the standard Bard class features though, so this may not be an option, if you would like to keep those.

Also, as starwed did in his answer, me too I advise you to talk to your GM to be less stringent with the feat's requirements.

Comment: Fire Music specifically requires that you cast the spell from not-bard. I agree it's a stupid requirement, but Magician isn't going to get around it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the wording, but I think the trait [two-world-magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/two-world-magic) may be relevant:

> Benefit: Select one 0-level spell from a class spell list other than your own. This spell is a 0-level spell on your class spell list (or a 1st-level spell if your class doesn't have 0-level spells). [...]

On one hand, it allows you to gain a spell from another class's spell list, but on the other hand, it becomes a spell in your list, so it might not qualify. Consult your GM...